# React Navigation getParam without the navigation prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I followed this guide https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html  for Navigating without the navigation prop. I am wondering if I can add `getParam` to my `NavigationService` to use that just like `navigation.getParam`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current route and its params using `onNavigationStateChange`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-tracking.html